# PHP cUrl request escaping problem (HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.)

Tags: php, api, curl, escaping

I am working on a WordPress plugin in PHP, using cUrl. My URL works for Postman, but not with cUrl. I've tried escaping the URL according to solutions I found online (second code example), but nothing seemed to work (I got a 404 - File or Directory on the second code example). Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong and tell me how to escape the URL correctly?

Code Example 1 (Throws 400 HTTP Error Code):
$searchstring is something like Ben Day which is exploded into Ben and Day ($nameSlice 1&2).

```
function get_Lehrer($searchstring) {

$fullname = splitWords($searchstring);


$token = api_token();

$curl = curl_init();

$nameSlice1 = $fullname[0];

$nameSlice2 = $fullname[1];

$url1 = 'ExampleUrl.com/Example'; <============= example data

$url2 = "?$"."filter=startswith(vorname,'" .$nameSlice1. "') or startswith(vorname,'" .$nameSlice1. "') or startswith(nachname,'" .$nameSlice2. "') or startswith(nachname,'" .$nameSlice2. "')";

$url = $url1 . $url2;

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' , 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token ));

$data = curl_exec($curl);

if(!$data) {
    die('Nani?');
}
else {
    echo $data;  <===================== I print the json directly, that's where I get the error code)
    $dataarray = json_decode($data);
}
curl_close($curl);
}
```

Code Example 2 where I get the 404 HTTP Error Code:

```
function get_Lehrer($searchstring) {

$fullname = splitWords($searchstring);


$token = api_token();

$curl = curl_init();

$nameSlice1 = $fullname[0];

$nameSlice2 = $fullname[1];

$url1 = 'ExampleUrl.com/Example'; <========= example data

$url2 = "?$"."filter=startswith(vorname,'" .$nameSlice1. "') or startswith(vorname,'" .$nameSlice1. "') or startswith(nachname,'" .$nameSlice2. "') or startswith(nachname,'" .$nameSlice2. "')";

$url = $url1 . curl_escape($curl, $url2);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' , 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token ));

$data = curl_exec($curl);

if(!$data) {
    die('Nani?');
}
else {
    echo $data;
    $dataarray = json_decode($data);
}
curl_close($curl);
//showData($dataarray, $searchmethod);
}
```

Comment: Use `urlencode()` to encode query parameters.

Comment: Or call `http_build_query()` and let it construct the query string automatically.